# Running bower from appharbor build

Tags: node.js, msbuild, bower, appharbor

I've searched on the web but couldn't find anything to fix my particular problem. I'm trying to deploy a WebApp to AppHarbor with some additional tasks but got a issue on build.

```
 <Target Name="NpmBuild"> <!--This part runs OK as AppHarbor machine has node installed-->
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="npm install bower -g" />
    <Exec Command="npm install gulp -g" />
    <Message Text="Npm Build Finished" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BowerBuild"> <!--This part fails because bower can't find Git-->
    <Exec Command="%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower.cmd install" />
    <Exec Command="%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower.cmd cache clean" />
    <Exec Command="%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower.cmd update" />
    <Message Text="Bower Build Finished" />
  </Target>
```

I edited the .csproj file as displayed above to run some tasks for the front-end build for my project where it installs npm then bower/gulp. Afterwards when it tries to run 'bower install' it displays this error:

**ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH**

The bower command is recognized but probably git is not installed on the machine that AppHarbor provides for the application.

My questions are:

Is there a way to install git in a AppHarbor machine (or access it)? If it is already installed how can i check it or get bower to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have used `git init` to make it works


 <Target Name="NpmBuild"> <!--This part runs OK as AppHarbor machine has node installed-->
        <Exec Command="git init" />
        <Exec Command="npm install" />
        <Exec Command="npm install bower -g" />
        <Exec Command="npm install gulp -g" />
        <Message Text="Npm Build Finished" />
      </Target>
      <Target Name="BowerBuild"> <!--This part fails because bower can't find Git-->
        <Exec Command="%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower.cmd install" />
        <Exec Command="%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower.cmd cache clean" />
        <Exec Command="%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower.cmd update" />
        <Message Text="Bower Build Finished" />
      </Target>
```